# Lucene term query

Tags: lucene

In my application we have deals and each deal has a target user group which may include several fields like gender, age and city. For the gender part a deal's target could be `MALE` `FEMALE` or `BOTH`. I wanted to find deals which are either for males or both.I created the following query but it doesn't work...

```
TermQuery maleQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("gender","MALE"));
TermQuery bothQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("gender","BOTH"));

BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
query.add(maleQuery,BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
query.add(bothQuery,BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
```

Please suggest if I am making some mistake. Somehow it seems to spit out only `MALE` deals,and not `BOTH`.

I am using version `4.2.1` and `Standard Analyzer` as the analyzer.

Comment: What is the search result of only `new TermQuery(new Term("gender","BOTH"))`?

Comment: it gives me items with gender specified as both... but it's very inconsistent. In a similar different query - `new TermQuery(new Term("type","DEAL"))` it doesn't give me the items with `type=DEAL`. The indexing of both the scenarios is exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several solutions possible are:

> 1. Use a `QueryParser` to construct the query instead of using `TermQuery` using the same  analyser used at indexing time.For eg in my case it would be:
>      Query query = new QueryParser(version,"gender",new StandardAnalyzer()).parse("MALE BOTH");
> 2. Use a different analyzer for indexing that does a case insensitive indexing.
> 3. (this one applies for StandardAnalyzer, for other analyzers solutions may be different)    LOWERCASE your search terms before searching.

## Explaination

A brief explaination to the situation would be:

I used a `StandardAnalyzer` for indexing which lower cases input tokens so that a case insensitive search could be materialised.

Then I used a `QueryParser` configured with the same analyzer to construct a query instance for searching the user's query at front end. The search worked because the parser working in accordance with standard analyzer lower cased the user's terms and made a case sensitive search.

Then I needed to filter search results for which I wrote `TermQuery`s instead of using parsers, in which I used capitalized text which was not indexed that way, so the search failed.

Answer (score 2):

Your query seems perfectly valid, I'd look for something else that might be wrong (e.g. are you not using `LowerCaseFilter` for `MALE/BOTH/FEMALE` terms by a chance when indexing?).

You might want to read [this article](http://searchhub.org/2011/12/28/why-not-and-or-and-not/) on how to combine various queries into a single `BooleanQuery`.

Comment: Hi mindas... I dont think there was a problem with lower case filtering. I used a `StandardAnalyzer` for both indexing and searching which is supposed to take care of case senstivity. Further the following different course works for me: 

    `new QueryParser(version,"gender",analyzer).parse("MALE BOTH");`
so case senstivity wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Oh my bad... perhaps you were right... I interpreted things in a wrong way... actually `StandardAnalyzer` lower cases all input before indexing and TermQuery makes a `case sensitive` search. When I use a parser it again creates a query with the support of a passed in analyzer, which in my case is `StandardAnalyzer` so it takes care of case insenstivity but the term query fails though.